# issue: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-layout

Iam developing app to add dynamic data to multiple table views.The structure is as follows.

[image]
My code in onPostExecute is :

```
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results){
int ind,i = 0;
ScrollView sv=null;
TableLayout tl=null;
TableRow tr = null;
int mjsonlength=results.size();
if(results!=null){

 TableLayout indextl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.indextablelayout);
    TableRow indextr=new TableRow(SubProducts.this);
    //indext1.moveToFirst();
    LinearLayout llt=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alltablell);
    //for(int f=0;f<mjsonlength;f++){

        for( ind=0;ind<indextitle.size();ind++)
        {

            TextView indextv=new TextView(SubProducts.this);
            indextv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenbg);
            indextv.setHeight(25);
            indextv.setWidth(50);
            indextv.setId(6);
            indextv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            indextv.setText(indextitle.get(ind));
            indextv.setPadding(20,10,6,3);
            indextr.addView(indextv);

            indextl.addView(indextr,6);

            sv=new ScrollView(SubProducts.this);
             tl=new TableLayout(SubProducts.this);
             for( i=0;i<mjsonlength;i++){
                    tr=new TableRow(SubProducts.this);

                    if(ind==i)  {

                        RelativeLayout rl=new RelativeLayout(SubProducts.this);
                        Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
                          rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.prd_box);

                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            image=new ImageView(SubProducts.this);
                            image.setLayoutParams(newParams1);
                            image.setId(1);
                            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            image.setPadding(5, 20, 5, 5);
                            rl.addView(image,1);



                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            lprams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1);

                          TextView tv1=new TextView(SubProducts.this);
                        Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(description.get(i));
                        tv1.setText((marked_up.toString()).substring(1, 170).replaceAll("&nbsp;",""));
                        tv1.setLayoutParams(lprams);
                        tv1.setId(2);
                        tv1.setHeight(150);
                        tv1.setWidth(130);
                        tv1.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 10);
                        rl.addView(tv1,2);


                         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                         newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 2);
                        TextView tv=new TextView(SubProducts.this);
                        tv.setText(productname.get(i));
                        tv.setLayoutParams(newParams);
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tv.setId(3);
                        tv.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 10);
                        rl.addView(tv,3);


                        tr.addView(rl);
                        tr.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);


                    }
                    tl.addView(tr);

            }

             sv.addView(tl);

                llt.addView(sv);

        }

    }
```

}

Iam getting error as follows:

```
     03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The 03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3339)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:402)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at com.example.nutritionplusapp.SubProducts$LongRunningGetIO1.onPostExecute(SubProducts.java:227)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at com.example.nutritionplusapp.SubProducts$LongRunningGetIO1.onPostExecute(SubProducts.java:1)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 06:32:07.586: I/Process(7233): Sending signal. PID: 7233 SIG: 9
03-16 06:32:08.522: E/Trace(7355): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

The loop variable value should be same  for both loops Inorder get subproducts of respective product.Iam fighting with the above error.Anybody having idea.Plz suggest me with proper solution.Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

```
ArrayList<String> productname=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> description=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> indextitle=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

under doINBackground:

```
 JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);

     manJson = json.getJSONObject("product");
     mStrings.add(manJson.getString("productimage"));
     productname.add(manJson.getString("productname"));
    indextitle.add(manJson.getString("subcategoryid"));
    description.add(manJson.getString("description"));
```

Comment: can u post declation and definition of indextitle collection on for loop

Comment: Thanq Dinesh.I have edited my question plz have a look.

Comment: Can you post your json string format?

Comment: thanq Dinesh..data is:[{"product":{"productimage": "img.jpg","subcategoryid":"prod1","productname":"name","description":"description"}},{"product":continues.....}}]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay the second potential problem is also:
indextl.addView(indextr);

indextr gets added every single loop iteration but it's the same view.  You can only add a view once to the hierarchy.  You probably want a new instance for each loop iteration.  I can't say for sure but this is likely the problem.

Comment: thanq James Baca It solved my problem.But it is showing only one product i mean it is showing only 1 subproduct of product1.Any problem in my looping.Plz go through it if you have any idea.

Comment: My guess would be this line: if(ind==i) this can only happen once for a subproduct...

Comment: can you suggest me any replacement logic instead of that.

Answer (score 7):

try this....

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mViewParent.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(mViewParent);
parent.removeView(mViewParent);

parent.addView(mNewView_U_want_to_add);
```

Answer (score 3):

In onCreate with activity or in onCreateView with fragment.

```
if (view != null) {
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
if (parent != null) {
    parent.removeView(view);
}
}try {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception actually looks like it is caused by:

`indextl.addView(indextr,6);`

The problem appears that you are trying to add the view at the 6th index, but there are not any items present:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:           index=6 count=0
```

Comment: thanq James Baca.I have solved it.But now Iam getting another error i.e.,03-16 06:27:07.452: E/AndroidRuntime(7233): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: James Baca I have updated my log file in question itself have a look.thanq